# Problem with Class 'Database\Seeders\ not found

Tags: php, database, class, lumen

recently i start to practice laravel/lumen.  Everything  was fine but now i am facing  a problem when i am going to try the command:  php artisan db:seed  It is showing me a error that:  Class 'Database\Seeders\lumenPractice' not found

i also tried:  php artisan migrate:fresh --seed it is also not working and showing me the same error. i am using php version 7.4.11`enter code here`

### my LumenPractice.php code are given below:

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Auth\Authenticatable;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Access\Authorizable as AuthorizableContract;
use Illuminate\Contracts\Auth\Authenticatable as AuthenticatableContract;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\HasFactory;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;
use Laravel\Lumen\Auth\Authorizable;

class LumenPractice extends Model
{
     /**
     * The attributes that are mass assignable.
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $fillable = [
    
        'name', 
        'gender',
        'country',
    ];
}
```

### My DatabaseSeeder.php code are given below:

```
<?php

namespace Database\Seeders;

use Illuminate\Database\Seeder;

class DatabaseSeeder extends Seeder
{
    /**
     * Run the database seeds.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function run()
    {
        
        //factory(lumenPractice::class(), 50)->create();
         lumenPractice::factory(count(30))->create();
        // $this->call('UsersTableSeeder');
    }
}
```

### My UserFactory.php code are given below:

```
<?php

namespace Database\Factories;

use App\Models\LumenPractice;
use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Factories\Factory;

class UserFactory extends Factory
{
    /**
     * The name of the factory's corresponding model.
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $model = LumenPractice::class;

    /**
     * Define the model's default state.
     *
     * @return array
     */
    public function definition()
    {
        return [
            'gender' =>$gender = $this->faker->randomElement(['male''female'])
            'name' => $this->faker->name($gender),
            'country' => $this->faker->country,
        ];
    }

    
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried capitalizing the "l" in `lumenPractice::factory(count(30))->create();`? I believe you meant to write `LumenPractice::factory(count(30))->create();` . Everything else seems fine.